# different cases about using List(List[A]()) and List[List[A]]() in scala?

Tags: scala

I was trying [scala-99](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/) P09.

The answer given by author is:

```
object P09 {
  def pack[A](ls: List[A]): List[List[A]] = {
    if (ls.isEmpty) List(List())
    else {
      val (packed, next) = ls span { _ == ls.head }
      if (next == Nil) List(packed)
      else packed :: pack(next)
    }
  }
}
```

It gives that:

```
pack(List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a, 'b, 'c, 'c, 'a, 'a, 'd, 'e, 'e, 'e, 'e))
// res0: List[List[Symbol]] = List(List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a), List('b), List('c, 'c), List('a, 'a), List('d), List('e, 'e, 'e, 'e))
```

and

```
pack(List[Int]()) // => res1: List[List[Int]] = List(List())
```

But, I think it should be `List[List[Int]] = List()`

For what reason, the author makes it return `List(List())` instead of `List()`?

### Added

Today, I come across P26(**Generate the combinations of K distinct objects chosen from the N elements of a list.**), which I gave the following solution at first:

```
def combinationsOf[A](n: Int, ls: List[A]): List[List[A]] = {
  if (n < 0 || n > ls.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException
  else if (n == 0) List.empty[List[A]]
  else if (n == ls.length) List(ls)
  else combinationsOf(n - 1, ls.tail).map(ls.head :: _) ::: combinationsOf(n, ls.tail)
}
```

But when given K = 3, and List(1,2,3,4), It only outputs `(1,2,4), (1,3,4), (2,3,4)`, which is wrong. I know what's wrong in my code. So I make it right:

```
def combinationsOf[A](n: Int, ls: List[A]): List[List[A]] = {
  if (n < 0 || n > ls.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException
  else if (n == 0) List(Nil)
  else if (n == ls.length) List(ls)
  else combinationsOf(n - 1, ls.tail).map(ls.head :: _) ::: combinationsOf(n, ls.tail)
}
```

What I cannot understand stands still. Why `List(Nil)` is needed when List() seems to be more suitable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Ninety-Nine Scala Problems](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/) page:

> These are an adaptation of the [Ninety-Nine Prolog Problems](https://sites.google.com/site/prologsite/prolog-problems) written by Werner Hett at the Berne University of Applied Sciences in Berne, Switzerland. I (Phil Gold) have altered them to be more amenable to programming in Scala. Feedback is appreciated, particularly on anything marked TODO.

Now, if you check the [Ninety-Nine Prolog Problems](https://sites.google.com/site/prologsite/prolog-problems) you'll see that problem 1.09 is basically the same problem listed here. The Prolog Problems site also provides solutions, and if you check [the solution for 1.09](https://sites.google.com/site/prologsite/prolog-problems/1/solutions-1) you'll see this:

```
pack([],[]).
```

I'm not much of a prolog programmer, but I'm pretty sure that means that an empty list as input results in an empty list as output. In the case where the input is the empty list, the [99 Lisp Problems](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2006s2/funcional/L-99_Ninety-Nine_Lisp_Problems.html) and [99 Haskel Problems](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions) solutions for this problem also give empty lists (not a list containing a single empty list).

I think the `List(List())` expression in the answer does look like it was just caused by confusion about how to create an empty list of lists. As @SpiderPig shows in his modified solution, returning a `List()` instead of `List(List())` actually does a lot to simplify the recursive logic.

The 99 Scala Problems page has a link for providing feedback, so you could always point out this problem and suggest a fix.

---

> What I cannot understand stands still. Why List(Nil) is needed when List() seems to be more suitable?

In the last case in your function you `map` over the results of all the recursive calls. If your recursive call returns `List()`, then you map over an empty list, which will always return an empty list. In contrast, `map(ls.head :: _)` will return `List(ls.head)` if `_` was `List(Nil)` instead of `List()`. You can fix this problem by adding another case for *n=1*:

```
def combinationsOf[A](n: Int, ls: List[A]): List[List[A]] = {
  require(0 <= n && n <= ls.length) // using require is probably better style
  if (n == 0) List()
  else if (n == 1) ls.map(List(_)) // fixes map over empty list problem
  else if (n == ls.length) List(ls)
  else combinationsOf(n - 1, ls.tail).map(ls.head :: _) ::: combinationsOf(n, ls.tail)
}
```

Also note that instead of explicitly throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`, I swapped the first case with a `require` (which throws an `IllegalArgumentException` if the clause is false).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know. I also think it should return an empty list if the input list is empty.
I would write it like this

```
def pack[A](ls: List[A]): List[List[A]] = {
  if (ls.isEmpty) List.empty[List[A]]
  else {
    val (packed, next) = ls span { _ == ls.head }
    packed :: pack(next)
  }
}
```

or even shorter

```
def pack[A](ls: List[A]): List[List[A]] = ls.groupBy(identity).values.toList
```

Comment: The "shorter" solution here is wrong because it doesn't maintain order, and it merges non-adjacent entries into a single group. I think your first solution is good though. If you look at the later problems you'll see that the user is expected to use this function to build a simplistic compression scheme (e.g. `a a a a b b b` => `(4 a) (3 b)`), so the order does matter.